# Trying to incorporate kitchen sink grid sample in Local app in Sencha/Extjs

Tags: extjs

Trying to incorporate kitchen sink grid sample in Local app in Sencha/Extjs

https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#array-grid

When I run sencha app watch open chrome tools inspector, I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isBufferedStore' of undefined`

Comment: Can you attach some simple reproducible code example?

Answer (score 2):

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isBufferedStore' of undefined" means the store in grid is undefined. Maybe you are using a store ID which is not registered as a global store..